# assert statement puzzling behaviour

Tags: assert

I'm using this really simple piece of code to understand how assert statements work.

```
public class TestAssertion {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
       boolean condition = true;
       assert condition;
       System.out.println("End of program");
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I run the program from command line with java -ea TestAssertion, I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError
    at TestAssertion.main(TestAssertion.java:4)

So if condition is true, why is assert throwing the error? Isn't this exactly the opposite of what it's supposed to do? I've tried running other assert statements as well and I keep getting the same error no matter what. 
Can someone explain please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out; I wasn't compiling the code (using javac) before running it. Turns out, working from the command line is really important.

Comment: To enable assertions in NetBeans go to Run > Set Project Configuration > Customize, then type in the VM Options box: -enableassertions.